# EntityFramework TPT inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple TPT Inheritance, EF 6.1.1

```
public class Base {
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Derived : Base {
     public int SomeProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Note that in my case `Base` is NOT an abstract class, because in my domain can exists an instance of `Base` without `Derived`. 
DbContext  :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext {

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Derived >().ToTable("Derived");
   }

   public DbSet<Base> BaseDbSet {get ; set; }
   public DbSet<Derived> DerivedDbSet {get ; set; }
}
```

Now,

1. I can Insert in BaseDbSet.
2. I can Delete from BaseDbSet.
3. Deleting from DerivedDbSet deletes only the Derived Entity.
4. Inserting in the DerivedDbSet insert also a new record in the Base Table, also if the Id is correct, creating a new Id.

I really don't understand point 4. How can I insert a record in the derived table without inserting a new one in the Base table?
I think the problem was related to identity column. It seems that when inserting EF doesn't care the Id of the Derived class, because the Id property has `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`, but I cannot specify different DatabaseGeneratedOption attribute in Base and Derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behaviour. A `Derived` entity can not exist without `Base` entity.

If you are inserting a `Derived` entity wich `Id` is not in `Base` table, EF insert a new tuple in `Base` and in `Derived`, writing `Id` in Base table and `SomeProperty` in `Derived` table. Any other behavior produce data corruption and inconsistency.

If what you are trying is create a `Derived` from a existing `Base` just follow this [link](http://books.google.es/books?id=rtdgHbMeTBMC&pg=PA372&lpg=PA373&dq=EF%20tpt%20create%20derived%20from%20existing%20base&source=bl&ots=kWph0ANzZF&sig=U01fsHCcM0Q4woKV7kCY_fDwXCk&hl=es&sa=X&ei=4QUkVIv5L4Hjav_hgng&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=EF%20tpt%20create%20derived%20from%20existing%20base&f=false) and read a bit.

Comment: Yes, I was triyng to create a `Derived` from an existing  `Base` and the link you post explains that is NOT supported by EF. I think this is a strong limitation that  makes TPT Inheritance less usefull. Creating a stored procedure for inserting Derived from Base is, in my opinion, something crazy.