# EntityFramwork Core and Inheritance TPT

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-core

I have read some posts, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036436/entityframework-tpt-inheritance), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63624654/entity-framework-core-tpt) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/modeling/inheritance).

Some tables from the database:

[image]

I migrated from EF4 creating the models using [Scaffold-DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463226/migrate-entity-framework-4-0-to-core), I expected it generates followings:

```
class Tagesinkassos {}
class TagesinkassosPOSTagesinkasso : Tagesinkassos {}
class TagesinkassosTagesinkasso : Tagesinkassos {}
```

instead I got:

```
class TagesinkassosPOSTagesinkasso {}
class TagesinkassosTagesinkasso {}
class Tagesinkassos {
    public virtual TagesinkassosPOSTagesinkasso TagesinkassosPOSTagesinkasso { get; set; }
    public virtual TagesinkassosTagesinkasso TagesinkassosTagesinkasso { get; set; }
}
```

I read that TPC is not supported in EFCore yet, but this is TPT, right?

However, if I modify the generated models, I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'TagesinkassosTagesinkasso' cannot be mapped to a table because it is derived from 'Tagesinkassos'. Only base entity types can be mapped to a table.'
```

Is it possible to modify the models or is there something in the DB that forces this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Table-per-Type` isn't supported in EF Core versions lower than 5.0. It was first added in [EF Core 5 Preview 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#table-per-type-tpt-mapping). If you want to use TPT you'll have to migrate to EF Core 5.

Currently EF Core 5 is in RC2 which can be used in production. From the [announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-ef-core-5-rc2/) :

> This is a feature complete release candidate of EF Core 5.0 and ships with a "go live" license. You are supported using it in production.

From the documentation's example, these classes :

```
[Table("Animals")]
public class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Species { get; set; }
}

[Table("Pets")]
public class Pet : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Cats")]
public class Cat : Pet
{
    public string EdcuationLevel { get; set; }
}

[Table("Dogs")]
public class Dog : Pet
{
    public string FavoriteToy { get; set; }
}
```

Will be mapped to these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Animals] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Species] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Animals] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [Pets] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Pets] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Pets_Animals_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) 
               REFERENCES [Animals] ([Id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE [Cats] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [EdcuationLevel] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Cats] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Cats_Animals_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) 
               REFERENCES [Animals] ([Id]) 
               ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Cats_Pets_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) 
               REFERENCES [Pets] ([Id]) 
               ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE [Dogs] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [FavoriteToy] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Dogs] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Dogs_Animals_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) 
               REFERENCES [Animals] ([Id]) 
               ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Dogs_Pets_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) 
               REFERENCES [Pets] ([Id]) 
               ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I misunderstod it.

Comment: I migrated to EFCore 5 rc, have an issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23011

Comment: They'll ask you for more information. The most likely reason is that there's no such property. The function you called refers to *properties*, not columns. Property names are case-sensitive

Comment: @Emaborsa you should use the overload that [accepts expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverindexbuilderextensions.includeproperties?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerIndexBuilderExtensions_IncludeProperties__1_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_IndexBuilder___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Object___) to avoid typos and casing problems

Comment: I agree with you, but it is a generated code from the scaffolding tool.

Comment: @Emaborsa that's a different question entirely. You'll have to explain that this code was generated by the scaffolding tool in that issue. If you included the classes and table schema it would be a lot easier for the EF Core team to reproduce and fix the problem. Don't ask them to guess what's going on two weeks before release

Comment: It updated my Models, but it does not work. I get `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table XXXX when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF`